# How to add a contact form template into another template?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm very new to this and I'm trying to create a simple website for a company using django 2.

I'm using this template that is a single page: https://html5up.net/astral

I want to make the contact form work but I can't manage.

I've tried putting `{% block %} {% endblock %}` in the HTML file but it won't render the form, `{% include %}` renders the html file I created but not the form. I was wondering if it is possible to make the form that is already rendered work.

Thanks!

Comment: This will probably help https://www.mastercode.online/tutorials/tutorial/how-to-display-a-form-on-more-than-one-template-in-django/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Template Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) to do this.

You have your "base.html" parent template which has a placeholder for the form:

```
  <html>
  ...
  <div ... >

      {% block contact-form %}
      {% endblock %}

  </div> 
  ...
  </html>
```

And your form is in "contact.html" child template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block contact-form  %}

 <!-- contact form content -->

{% endblock %}
```

Then in your url patterns direct peeps to the view that renders the child "contact.html" template.

The {% extends %} tag lets the template engine know that it must first load the parent "base.html" and then fill in the appropriate block with the child "contact.html" template's content.

Comment: The problem is that the url pattern is something lie #contact, and is in the same base html. I don't if this means anything but I can only make the form appear if I make another url. Even though it appears, it messes up the page because then, the content of the other panel shows up in the contact panel.

Comment: Not knowing how your views are set up, but it may be simplest if you just pass the form in as part of the context object arg to your render() method, and then just add a {{ form }} tag to your page template.